# How to remove minimize button in PySide

Tags: python, qt4, qt5, pyside

How can I remove the minimize button from **QMainWindow in Python**?

I'm using **Python 3.4** with **PySide**.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to utilize [`setWindowFlags`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setWindowFlags) do prevent the minimize and maximize button from appearing. You'll have to set the [appropriate flags](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qt.html#WindowType-enum) as well.

In this case, you need to enable `CustomizeWindowHint` and then disable *both* `WindowMinimizeButtonHint` and `WindowMaximizeButtonHint` (alternatively, you could just disable `WindowMinMaxButtonsHint`, which handles the previous two flags).

A very simple program demonstrating how this works:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250, 150)
    w.move(300, 300)
    w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
    w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() & QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
    w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMinMaxButtonsHint)
    w.show()   
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Outputs:

[image: No Min/Max buttons]

Comment: My problem was I defined it in the class, after i moved it to the main it goes right